# Blade foreach cast output to an object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to figure out how I can give my data output in the blade file, the Laravel look;

> like `$data->name`

But I can't get the output to be casted as an object. I think I have to make an array of the data before I can loop it proper in a `foreach` but this doesn't feel like the right way.

I am relatively new to Laravel and I want to do this the nice way, can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance

Controller:

```
$data = collect($this->api->organization->index())->toArray();

return View::make('pages.organization.index', array('data' => $data[0]));
```

View:

```
@foreach($data as ((object)$organization))
    {{ $organization->name }}
@endforeach
```

I know this will not work, but I  think it illustrates my question a little bit.

**EDIT**

What I didn't realize is that `$data = collect($this->api->organization->index());` is returning an array with all the data arrays inside because I didn't name it in my return like this:

```
return (object)['all' => $data];
```

After adding `all` I could reference the code inside my view like I wanted to. I know this is not a very detailed answer, if you run into the same problem message me I'll edit the answer.

Comment: `$data = collect($this->api->organization->index());` will give the collection of array of objects i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object:

```
$data = collect($this->api->organization->index());
@foreach($data as $organization))
    {{ $organization->name }}
@endforeach
```

Array:

```
$data = collect($this->api->organization->index())->toArray();
@foreach($data as $organization))
    {{ $organization['name'] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: This made me realize I need to name the object `return (object)['obj' => $data];` and call it like `..->index()->obj` and that made it work!